# Functional way of interrupting lazy iteration depedning on timeout and comparisson between previous and next, while, LazyList vs Stream

Tags: scala, functional-programming

## Background

I have the following scenario. I want to execute the method of a class from an external library, repeatedly, and I want to do so until a certain timeout condition and result condition (compared to the previous result) is met. Furthermore I want to collect the return values, even on the "failed" run (the run with the "failing" result condition that should interrupt further execution).

Thus far I have accomplished this with initializing an empty `var result: Result`, a `var stop: Boolean` and using a `while` loop that runs while the conditions are true and modifying the outer state. I would like to get rid of this and use a functional approach.

Some context. Each run is expected to run from 0 to 60 minutes and the total time of iteration is capped at 60 minutes. Theoretically, there's no bound to how many times it executes in this period but in practice, it's generally 2-60 times.

The problem is, the runs take a long time so I need to stop the execution.  My idea is to use some kind of lazy `Iterator` or `Stream` coupled with `scanLeft` and `Option`.

## Code

### Boiler plate

This code isn't particularly relevant but used in my approach samples and provide identical but somewhat random pseudo runtime results.

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import scala.util.Random
val r = Random
r.setSeed(1)
val sleepingTimes: Seq[Int] = (1 to 601)
  .map(x => Math.pow(2, x).toInt * r.nextInt(100))
  .toList
  .filter(_ > 0)
  .sorted
val randomRes = r.shuffle((0 to 600).map(x => r.nextInt(10)).toList)
case class Result(val a: Int, val slept: Int)
class Lib() {
  def run(i: Int) = {
    println(s"running ${i}")
    Thread.sleep(sleepingTimes(i))
    Result(randomRes(i), sleepingTimes(i))
  }
}
case class Baz(i: Int, result: Result)
val lib = new Lib()
val timeout = 10 * 1000
```

### While approach

```scala
val iteratorStart = System.currentTimeMillis()
val iterator = for {
  i <- (0 to 600).iterator
  if System.currentTimeMillis() < iteratorStart + timeout
  f = Baz(i, lib.run(i))
} yield f
val iteratorBuffer = ListBuffer[Baz]()
if (iterator.hasNext) iteratorBuffer.append(iterator.next())
var run = true
while (run && iterator.hasNext) {
  val next = iterator.next()
  run = iteratorBuffer.last.result.a < next.result.a
  iteratorBuffer.append(next)
}
```

### Stream approach (Scala.2.12)

[Full example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/fJZqiBJLSyu4ix8ZVJgeDw)

```scala
val streamStart = System.currentTimeMillis()
val stream = for {
  i <- (0 to 600).toStream
  if System.currentTimeMillis() < streamStart + timeout
} yield Baz(i, lib.run(i))
var last: Option[Baz] = None
val head = stream.headOption
val tail = if (stream.nonEmpty) stream.tail else stream
val streamVersion = (tail
  .scanLeft((head, true))((x, y) => {
    if (x._1.exists(_.result.a > y.result.a)) (Some(y), false)
    else (Some(y), true)
  })
  .takeWhile {
    case (baz, continue) =>
      if (!baz.eq(head)) last = baz
      continue
  }
  .map(_._1)
  .toList :+ last).flatten
```

LazyList approach (Scala 2.13)

[Full example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/QYIuPD7nQqmvxyApadYNqQ)

```scala
val lazyListStart = System.currentTimeMillis()
val lazyList = for {
  i <- (0 to 600).to(LazyList)
  if System.currentTimeMillis() < lazyListStart + timeout
} yield Baz(i, lib.run(i))
var last: Option[Baz] = None
val head = lazyList.headOption
val tail = if (lazyList.nonEmpty) lazyList.tail else lazyList
val lazyListVersion = (tail
  .scanLeft((head, true))((x, y) => {
    if (x._1.exists(_.result.a > y.result.a)) (Some(y), false)
    else (Some(y), true)
  })
  .takeWhile {
    case (baz, continue) =>
      if (!baz.eq(head)) last = baz
      continue
  }
  .map(_._1)
  .toList :+ last).flatten
```

## Result

<s>Both approaches appear to yield the correct end result:</s>

```scala
List(Baz(0,Result(4,170)), Baz(1,Result(5,208)))
```

and they interrupt execution as desired.

**Edit:** The desired outcome is to not execute the next iteration but still return the result of the iteration that caused the interruption. Thus the desired result is

```scala
List(Baz(0,Result(4,170)), Baz(1,Result(5,208)), Baz(2,Result(2,256))
```

and `lib.run(i)` should only run 3 times.

This is achieved by the `while` approach, as well as the `LazyList` approach but not the `Stream` approach which executes `lib.run` 4 times (Bad!).

## Question

Is there another stateless approach, which is hopefully more elegant?

## Edit

I realized my examples were faulty and not returning the "failing" result, which it should, and that they kept executing beyond the stop condition. I rewrote the code and examples but I believe the spirit of the question is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use something higher level, like [**fs2**](https://fs2.io/).
*(or any other high-level streaming library, like: **monix observables**, **akka streams** or **zio zstreams**)*

```
def runUntilOrTimeout[F[_]: Concurrent: Timer, A](work: F[A], timeout: FiniteDuration)
                                                 (stop: (A, A) => Boolean): Stream[F, A] = {
  val interrupt =
    Stream.sleep_(timeout)

  val run =
    Stream
      .repeatEval(work)
      .zipWithPrevious                                         
      .takeThrough {
        case (Some(p), c) if stop(p, c) => false
        case _                          => true
      } map {
        case (_, c) => c
      }

  run mergeHaltBoth interrupt
}
```

You can see it working [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/rDxOpqVRTCiO45AVici5fA/15).

Comment: Thank you. This looks interesting! This still runs each iteration sequentially, right?

Comment: apologies but the question I posted wasn't complete. What I meant to ask for was a way to also return the "failing" result. In the case of your example, that would entail returning `List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`. Would that be possible with this approach?

Comment: @CervEd see the edited answer. A **Stream** provides a [lot of useful operations](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/co/fs2/fs2-core_2.12/2.2.1/fs2-core_2.12-2.2.1-javadoc.jar/!/fs2/Stream.html). If you are new to any of the mentioned libraries, it would be good to first start with basic FP concepts on **cats** and then proceed with the `IO` monad on **cats-effect**.